# Jython Coding Issue

Tags: python, jython

Design a program that lets the user enter the total rainfall for each of 12 months into a list. The program should calculate and display the total rainfall for the year, the average monthly rainfall, and the months with the highest and lowest amounts.

```
def main():
January = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of January:") 
February = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of February:") 
March = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of March:") 
April = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of April:") 
May = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of May:") 
June = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of June:") 
July = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of July:") 
August= requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of August:") 
September = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of September:") 
October = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of October:") 
November = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of November:") 
December = requestNumber ("Enter the amount of rainfall for the month of December:") 

Year = [January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December] 

total_rainfall = (sum(Year))
showInformation("The total rainfall for the year is:" + str(total_rainfall))

monthly_average = (sum(Year)) / 12
showInformation ("The monthly average for the year is:" +  str(monthly_average))
```

This is my code i have so far. I am really struggling on how to do the last part of the question which is to display the month with the highest and lowest amounts of rain. I know how to show the number using max and min but i dont know how to get the month which corresponds to the max and min amount of rain.

Thanks for any help anyone can give me, this is in Jython.

Comment: store the values as a dictionary `{January : 12}` . then you can easily read the `values` in a list and then get the lowest and highest

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Add list of Month names to your program:

```
Names = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
Year = [January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December]
```

then, once input from user obtained, sort both lists at the same time:

```
monthsSorted = sorted( zip(Names, Year), cmp=lambda (x1, y1), (x2, y2) : y2 - y1 )

print "MAX=%s" % str(monthsSorted[0])
print "MIN=%s" % str(monthsSorted[-1:])
```

zip() will create list like this out of two:

```
zip( [1,2,3], [a,b,c] ) -> [(1,a), (2,b), (3, c)]
```

this then sorted on second component (amount of rain).

Now biggest month is at front of monthsSorted and smallest is the last element of it.

Solution 2:
Iterate over all the elements comparing them with each other, like the one round of *bubble sort*:

```
print "MAX=%s" % str( reduce(lambda (x1, y1), (x2, y2) : (x1, y1) if y1 > y2 else (x2, y2), zip(Names, Year)) )

print "MIN=%s" % str ( reduce(lambda (x1, y1), (x2, y2) : (x1, y1) if y1 < y2 else (x2, y2), zip(Names, Year)) )
```